# Django + js Framework

Tags: javascript, python, django, frameworks

I want to develop a web application using Django, but I can't decide which javascript framework to use. May be some of you guys has developed Django + JS Framework application? I personally prefer JQuery because it is easy and fast, but other libraries like Dojo has so cool features and widgets. That I want to switch to it! What do you guys think? Thanks in advance!

Comment: jquery has a better ecosystem than dojo and here is why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394601/which-javascript-framework-jquery-vs-dojo-vs

Comment: application that is going to be developed is planned to be big with lots of features

Answer (score 3):

If you already have experience with jQuery, then go on with **jQuery**!

I use Django + jQuery + Postgresql for all my projects and couldn't be any happier with this powerful combination.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery and Scriptaculous are good choices,
But if you want to develop desktop like functionality over the web Qooxdoo helps alot :-)

Answer (score 1):

My vote goes for pyjamas (which I use myself):
http://pyjs.org/

It's basically a Python version of GWT. If you're already using Django, you might as well write your entire web-app in python and avoid having to maintain multiple languages.

Here is a quick Django + Pyjamas tutorial:
http://code.google.com/p/pyjamas/wiki/DjangoWithPyjamas

Don't get me wrong, I love jQuery, but having all my code in Python makes it a lot easier to maintain.

Comment: I still believe from a skill set and flexibility perspective going with javascript + some framework like jquery is a better way to go about it.