# django + javascript Application framework (not Jquery)?

Tags: python, ajax, django, frameworks

Step up from the [Django + jQuery / Prototype question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6314746/django-js-framework)...

Can anyone tell me about their experience with a UI application framework like YUI or spoutcore, but that works best with django?

Comment: after looking a bit further the javascript MVC frameworks are a client side solution: http://stackoverflow.com/q/386885/103969. on the server side dojo can be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I've found that jQuery (or jQuery UI if you like) is always a solid choice no matter what you're building, and I always end up using it with Django (or any other language/framework for that matter).  Users almost always have it cached in their browsers, it's easy to use/learn, tons of examples on the net, and other developers probably already know it.

Technically you should be able to set up almost any JS framework you like with Django, but some might require more 'setting up' than others.

Comment: well we just finished a pretty big project with just JQuery/JQueryUI and having to write all the process and error code was a big onerous.  hoping to find out something more comprehensive that handles the closure and standard controls more completely...

Comment: also not any framework will work.. sproutcore is tied pretty much to ruby and GWT is written in java...

Comment: Good point.  I wasn't aware of any that couldn't, but I did use 'almost'!  I guess technically you could extend jQuery to fit your needs.